# Plot validation and training accuracy/scores for each iteration of a GradientBoostingRegressor model?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression, decision-tree

I am using the `sklearn` library for gradient boosted regression. What I would like to do, is plot the validation and training accuracy (or MSE) through each estimator iteration. I see methods for obtaining the training scores, `GradientBoostingRegressor.train_score_`, and while this is something that I would be willing to fall back on if obtaining the accuracy is too difficult, but I can not find a method for obtaining the validation scores per iteration.

`cross_val_score` only produces an array of length *n* where *n* is the number of dataset splits * number of validation repeats. However, the length of the array that `train_score` produces is the same length as the number of estimators I provide for my regression model.

For example, if I have a model with `n_estimators = 1000`, `train_score` will contain 1000 entries. I would like to obtain the validation scores for each `estimator` as well such that I can plot `train_score` vs. `n_estimators` and `cross_val_score` vs. `n_estimators`.

Comment: Have you tried using [learning_curve](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.learning_curve.html#sklearn.model_selection.learning_curve)?

Comment: I looked into this but it seems to mainly be related to dataset size rather than training iterations.

Answer (score 1):

I iterated through `GradientBoostingRegresssor.estimators_` and found the average `cross_val_score()` for each estimator. I appended these values to an array and plotted them alongside `GradientBoostingRegressor.train_score_` later on. However, what I found was that the validation scores represented a horizontal line. I am unsure as to why the validation score would not be improving over each estimator iteration.